# Array function dynamic select query with Rails in pg

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model let say `Model` there is a field which is `serialized` in `Postgresql`. There is one more table which is `Role` and there ids are `::uuid`.

I want to fetch one additional field (alias like 'as new_field') which contains the result of the particular operation. When I run it manually with single value then it works fine but when I convert it to dynamically then it through syntax error.

Here is my `query` with single value:

```
Model.select("models.role_ids @> '{\"fe8fea09-869c-4a40-ab80-87623be70399\"}'::uuid[] as new_field").first.new_field

# SELECT  models.role_ids @> '{"fe8fea09-869c-4a40-ab80-87623be70399"}'::uuid[] as tes FROM "models"   ORDER BY "models"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> false
```

It runs the query correctly.

Then I tried it with my array:

1) When placing array's value in query:

```
Model.select('models.role_ids @> ARRAY[?]::uuid[] as new_field', user.role_ids)
```

Here `user` is User object which has HABTM association and 'role_ids' is the mediator table ids. Please let me know if I forgot something to mentioned

```
Query log:
Model Load (2.2ms)  SELECT models.role_ids @> ARRAY[?]::uuid[] as new_field, fe8fea09-869c-4a40-ab80-87623be70399 FROM "models"
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "]"
LINE 1: SELECT models.role_ids @> ARRAY[?]::uuid[] as new...
                                                        ^
: SELECT models.role_ids @> ARRAY[?]::uuid[] as new_field, fe8fea09-869c-4a40-ab80-87623be70399 FROM "models"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "]"
LINE 1: SELECT models.role_ids @> ARRAY[?]::uuid[] as new...
```

Please let me know if there is any option.